# ngx-imageviewer MissingPDFException

Tags: angular

ngx-imageviewer not displaying pdf. Displaying error:

> e {name: "MissingPDFException", message: "Missing PDF "http://localhost:4200/dashboard/product-overview/assets/aua.PDF"."}

What shall I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your problem in more detail and deliver a minimal example, please? Did you already read the information regarding questioning which is provided on SO, e.g. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: hi,
I have a pdf named aua.pdf in my assets folder. I'm using ngx-imageviewer to display it. But I'm getting error "e {name: "MissingPDFException", message: "Missing PDF "http://localhost:4200/dashboard/product-overview/assets/aua.pdf"."}"